# Help with an operator expansion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators

Is there an elegant form for $ (a^\dagger - ka)^n$ ? with $[a ,a^\dagger]=1$?

Comment: Define "elegant form" here.

Comment: I need to operate this expansion on the vacuum state. I look for the normal ordinate form, or anything that is easy to act on |0>

Answer (score 4):

Supposedly Einstein once began a lecture on special relativity for his physics students by saying "Everything that follows has now been done more elegantly by Minkowski, but chalk is cheaper than gray *[i.e. brain]* matter, we will take it as it comes," and then did it a somewhat harder way. That's basically the story of my M.Sc. too; it was a lot of "let's brute force this to get an immediate answer then mine it for the patterns that I want to prove." Here's how that looks for your problem.

Let $(a^\dagger + ka)^n |0\rangle = \sum_{p} \alpha^{(n)}_{p} |p\rangle,$ then for $n=0$ we have $\alpha^{(0)}_p = \delta_{0p}$ (i.e. $1$ if $p=0$, $0$ otherwise) and you derive the recurrence,$$\alpha^{(n)}_p = \alpha^{(n-1)}_{p-1} + k ~ \alpha^{(n-1)}_{p+1} .$$

Iterating through you find:

```
a0 = [1]
a1 = [0, 1]
a2 = [k, 0, 1]
a3 = [0, 2k, 0, 1]
a4 = [2k^2, 0, 3k, 0, 1]
a5 = [0, 5k^2, 0, 4k, 0, 1]
a6 = [5k^3, 0, 9k^2, 0, 5k, 0, 1]
```

Then you work to formally extract patterns. For example, the most obvious pattern is that everything is alternating with 0; in this case it looks very much like we might simplify by restricting ourselves to $n = 2m,$ with $\beta^{(m)}_q = \alpha^{(2m)}_{2q}.$ Substituting the above expression into itself gives
$$\alpha^{(n)}_p = \alpha^{(n-2)}_{p-2} + 2k ~ \alpha^{(n-2)}_{p} + k^2 ~ \alpha^{(n-2)}_{p+2} ,$$
or, $$\beta^{(m)}_q = \beta^{(m-1)}_{q-1} + 2k \beta^{(m-1)}_q + k^2 \beta^{(m-1)}_{q + 1}.$$ The next most obvious pattern is that $\beta^{(m)}_q$ appears to be some $c^{(m)}_q ~k^{m-q}$ and substituting that in we see that indeed these factors of $k$ drop out, proving that it must have that form with the coefficients: $$
c^{(m)}_q  = c^{(m-1)}_{q-1} + 2 c^{(m-1)}_q + c^{(m-1)}_{q + 1}
$$except that (as in the above expression for $\beta$) we have to special-case $c^{(m)}_0 = c^{(m-1)}_0 + c^{(m-1)}_1.$ Writing out a computer program to do some more of these:

```
c0 = [1]
c1 = [1, 1]
c2 = [2, 3, 1]
c3 = [5, 9, 5, 1]
c4 = [14, 28, 20, 7, 1]
c5 = [42, 90, 75, 35, 9, 1]
c6 = [132, 297, 275, 154, 54, 11, 1]
c7 = [429, 1001, 1001, 637, 273, 77, 13, 1]
c8 = [1430, 3432, 3640, 2548, 1260, 440, 104, 15, 1]
```

Looking up $c_0^{(m)}$ as a sequence in OEIS says that these are most likely [A000108, the Catalan numbers](http://oeis.org/A000108), with formula $(2n)!\over n!(n+1)!$. Our "special case" gives $c_1^{(m)}$ as a difference of Catalan numbers which is [A000245](http://oeis.org/A000245), $3~(2n)!\over(n+2)!(n-1)!$. The sequence $c_2^{(m)}$ appears to be [A000344](http://oeis.org/A000344), which it gives a similar formula as `5*binomial(2n,n-2)/(n+3)`, and the sequence $c_3^{(m)}$ appears to be A000588, `a(n) = 7*binomial(2n,n-3)/(n+4).`

There's of course a nontrivial mapping between `n` and `m` above, possibly something like `n = m - q` or so, but all of these seem to start with a $(2r + 1)(2n)!$ in the numerator and something like  $(n-r)!(n+r+1)!$ in the denominator. If you massage that pattern sufficiently you should hopefully be able to prove the actual pattern from the above recurrence formula, unless this happens to be an exceptionally lucky coincidence. And then after a week steeped in the Catalan numbers you'll presumably go "of course it has to go like that! How could it possibly be otherwise?!".

Answer (score 0):

As I said, my intention was to get a closed formula for the expression

$(a^\dagger-\kappa a)^n|0> $, that is, act this expansion on the vacuum state. After several tries I finally found out that the closed formula is

$ \sum^n_j (-\kappa)^j n!/ (2^jj! \sqrt (n-2j)!) |n-2j>$